# Having issue with do while loop in C while doing multiple conditions

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, do-while, cs50

I want to run the loop unless n>0 and less than 23. I have written the code below but it doesn't seem to be working. Although if I write one condition at a time the program works fine. But when I use the && operator it fails

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i, j, k, n;
    do
    {
        printf("Height: ");
        n = GetInt();
    }
    while(n<0 && n>23);

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (k = 1; k <= n - i; k++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can n be negative **and** greater than 23?

Comment: n cannot be lesser than 0 and greater than 23 at the same time. Review your loop condition.

Comment: I need to use the OR condition...OHH I get it. thanks

Comment: This can't be good: `do {} while(n<0 && n>23);`  Q: When will n ever be less than zero, and at the same time, greater than 23?  I think maybe you mean `||`...

Answer (score 1):

&& operator means both condition must be true at same time.
n can't be less than zero and greater than 23 at same time and so your condition fails irrespective of any input given and stored in n.

Use OR operator instead.

```
do
{

....

}while(n<0 || n>23);
```

means continue in loop till EITHER of condition holds true.

Comment: Yes, I got it finally. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

What you probably wanted is a logical OR:

```
while(n<0 || n>23);
```

Because n can't be less than zero **and** bigger than 23 at the same time. But n can be negative **or** bigger than 23.

Comment: Yes, I got it finally. Thanks :)